# How to parse second level JSON Array using jquery ajax

Tags: javascript, jquery, json, ajax

Hi Below is code of second level json array parsing. First level json output i can able to fetch. second level i cant. i.e under **CategoryImage** i have two attributes which i couldn't able to fetch can anyone help on this.Thanks

```
<script>        
        $(document).ready(function() {
          var cat="";
           categories(cat);
            $('ul li').click(function(){
                var cat = $(this).text();               
                categories(cat);               
            });
        });
        function categories(cat){                
             $.ajax({
                    url: "http://devcda.bryant.com/bryant/en/us/CommonSearchHandler.ashx?type=17&blogcategories="+cat,                                  dataType: "text",                   
                    success: function(data) {                        
                        var json = $.parseJSON(data);
                        var e="";
                        $(".blog_desc").remove();
                       for(var i in  json.ResultPayload){


                           e+="<div class='blog_desc'>";
                           e+="<div class='tmpstr_hdr_cntnt container'>";
                           e+=" <div class='col-lg-9 col-md-10 col-sm-10 col-xs-12'>"  ;
                           e+="<h3>"+json.ResultPayload[i].DisplayTitle+"</h3>";
                           e+="<p><span class='date_blg'>"+json.ResultPayload[i].CreationDate+"</span>Categories: <span class='cat_blg'>"+json.ResultPayload[i].BlogCategories+"</span></p>";                          
                           e+="<div class='col-lg-3 col-md-3 col-sm-3 col-xs-12'><img src="+json.ResultPayload[i].CategoryImage[i].Path+" class='img-responsive'>  </div>";

                           e+="<div class='col-lg-9 col-md-9 col-sm-9 col-xs-12'><p>"+json.ResultPayload[i].LongDescription+"</p>";
                           e+="<p class='read_more'><a href="+json.ResultPayload[i].PageURL+">READ MORE</a></p>";
                           e+="</div>";                        
                           e+="</div>"; 
                           e+="</div>";
                           e+="</div>";
                          } 


                        $("input").after(e);

                    }
                });


        }

    </script>
```

## Json file

```
{  
   "CurrentPage":0,
   "Facets":null,
   "RecordCount":4,
   "ResultPayload":[  
      {  
         "Name":null,
         "URI":"tcm:688-98862",
         "BlogCategories":[  
            "Efficiency"
         ],
         "CreationDate":"September 01, 2015",
         "DisplayTitle":"How often should you change your furnace filter?",
         "LongDescription":"How often should you change your furnace filter? How often should you change your furnace filter?How often should you change your furnace filter?How often should you change your furnace filter?How often should you change your furnace filter?How often should you change your furnace filter?",
         "PageURL":""
      },
      {  
         "Name":null,
         "URI":"tcm:688-98863",
         "BlogCategories":[  
            "Air Quality"
         ],
         "CreationDate":"September 01, 2015",
         "DisplayTitle":"Test",
         "LongDescription":"Test",
         "PageURL":""
      },
      {  
         "Name":null,
         "URI":"tcm:688-98798",
         "BlogCategories":[  
            "Air Quality"
         ],
         "CreationDate":"September 01, 2015",
         "DisplayTitle":"Test",
         "LongDescription":"Test",
         "PageURL":"\/bryant\/en\/us\/about-bryant\/blog\/blog-details\/Test%20Air%20quality.aspx"
      },
      {  
         "Name":null,
         "URI":"tcm:688-96383",
         "BlogCategories":[  
            "Efficiency"
         ],
         "CategoryImage":{  
            "AltText":"Blog_Detail_12345",
            "Path":"\/\/files.dev.bryant.com\/Bryant\/en\/us\/contentimages\/Blog_Detail_12345.png"
         },
         "CreationDate":"September 01, 2015",
         "DisplayTitle":"How often should you change your furnace filter?",
         "LongDescription":"How often should you change your furnace filter? How often should you change your furnace filter?How often should you change your furnace filter?How often should you change your furnace filter?How often should you change your furnace filter?How often should you change your furnace filter?",
         "PageURL":"\/bryant\/en\/us\/about-bryant\/blog\/blog-details\/How%20often%20should%20you%20change%20your%20furnace%20filter.aspx"
      }
   ],
   "suggestions":null
}
```

Comment: can you provide js fiddle for the same?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

CategoryImage is not an array so  ResultPayload[i].CategoryImage.Path should work

Comment: Thanks calinaadi..I tired someother way and fixed